# flask-sqlalchemy - change lazy in different situations

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Take the example in document

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', lazy='dynamic',
        backref=db.backref('person', lazy='select'))
```

We can only set the **lazy** parameter to **relationship** when we build the **models**. But I found no document show how to change it after  instantiated it.

In most of my situation like

```
user = User.query.first()
addresses = user.addresses.filter(is_del=0).all()
```

which is One-to-Many or

```
wallet = user.wallet
```

which is One-to-One Model, I just set the **lazy** to **dynamic or select** to let the model only get data what I need.

However recently I want to export the data in database using Admin Front-end page.

```
user_list = UserModel.query.all()
for x in user_list:
    item = {
        "ID": x.id if x.id else ''
    }
    if 'basic' in fields or is_all_field == 1:
        ex_item = {
            "Email": x.base.account,
            "Full Name": x.base.full_name,
            "Display Name": x.display_name if x.display_name else '',
            "Phone Number": x.base.phone_number if x.base.phone_number else '',
            "Status": status_map(x.is_sharer,x.is_block,x.status_id)
            "Register Time": x.create_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') if x.create_date else ''
        }
        item = {**item, **ex_item}
    if ......
    ........
```

If I continue to use select and dynamic as **lazy**. It will be very very slow cause every loop the parent query will access database every time when it use subquery.

I test the speed between **select** and **joined** using single field like `"Full Name": x.base.full_name` to export all user data. **Select** got 53s and **joined** got 0.02s.

Is there a way to change the **lazy** parameter based on not changing the original Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#controlling-loading-via-options) you can use `options` to define the type of loading you want. I believe it will override your default value defined in your relationship

Useful links

[Joined Loads](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload)

[Select Loads](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.selectinload)

[Lazy Load](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.lazyload)

Comment: Thanks it is very helpful. I just focused the flask-sqlalchemy document not to go through the sqlalchemy's one.

Comment: According to the doc, using flask-sqlalchemy should be `User.query.options(joinedload(User.addresses, innerjoin=True)).all()`

Comment: @Hustwhw Hi, did you ever figure this out? When i run your query i get "User does not support object population - eager loading cannot be applied."

Answer (score 3):

So, basically, if you are using `lazy=' select'`, lazy load, and want to switch to joinedload to optimize your query, use the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload  # import the joinedload 
user_list = db.session.query(UserModel).options(joinedload("person"))  # running a joinedload which will give you access to all attributes in parent and child class 
for x in user_list: 
    # now use x.account directly
```